# Enhance Journalctl to show /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, centos, logs, syslog, systemd-journald

I am not able to find /var/log/messages under journald. Is there any way I can integrate journald with /var/log/messages such that **journalctl** shows logs from **/var/log/messages**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have changed the configuration related to the logging system, Journald is absolutely *not* guaranteed to have everything that is in `/var/log/messages`.

Following up with this post about [LEMP troubleshooting with journalctl](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/using-journalctl-as-the-ultimate-utility-for-troubleshooting-lemp-stacks#how-it-works), the default setup work in a way that only a fraction of messages are actually stored in Journald:

> Both are installed and running:
>
> - Journald runs *without* persistent storage and stores log data only in RAM
> - Rsyslog (aka /var/log/messages and friends) persists log data to flat files
>   ...
>
> Rsyslog will persist much of the logs, while Journald will store only a fraction of already-persisted messages, in RAM.

If you want both log storages (Journald and Rsyslog) to be on par, at very minimum you should allocate persistent storage on the file system, and/or increase the RAM for Journald logs.

To make for a persistent storage, you'd simply create `/var/log/journal` directory and reload Journald daemon:

```
# create the directory
mkdir -p /var/log/journal
# ensure the write permissions
systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
# ping the daemon that the directory is there
killall -USR1 systemd-journald
```